# What is the maximum recommended routing distance between MAC and PHY?

Tags: ethernet

Picture to Keep the Terminology Clear:

[image: im]

I plan to use ETH for inter-processor communication. I need a few ETH lanes to be shared between boards. I wish to avoid ETH PHY and magnetics, as the interface is between two processors only.

I have a few RGMII outputs coming from a TI-TDA2x, which needs to be taken to a back-plane. From the back plane, I shall take it to another board having TI-TDA2x.

I want to know what is the maximum safe distance between MAC to PHY which can be maintained?

TI-TDA2X: [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/product/TDA2HG)

My Speed Requirement: 1 Gbps

Answer (score 2):

MII and RMII have round-trip time restrictions, since the TX data path on MII is destination synchronous, and the RX data path on RMII is destination synchronous.
Both RMII and MII hit a hard timing limit at a few hundred millimeters trace length.

RGMII on the other hand is fully source synchronous, which means it has no hard timing limit on the trace lengths.
It simply becomes an exercise in signal integrity and length matching.
With for example length and impedance matched coaxial cables and terminations you should be able to go quite far.

That said, SGMII or 1000BASE-X is better suited than RGMII for board-to-board ethernet backplane situations like this.

Answer (score -1):

Without reading the datasheet, 1Gigabit is 1 nanosecond. On FR-4, with Er of about 4, the 1_foot in air becomes about 1/2_foot in epoxy-fiberglass combined with air above. You may need to tolerate round trip reflections and/or ISI energy stored in the IC leadframe and bondwires and PCB vias and Silicon ESD non-linear capacitances. Thus round trip will be 1/4 foot per side, or 3" (7.5 cm). If the link has adaptive equalization, life should be very good.

Comment: 1) 1000BASE-T isn't 1 GHz; between scrambling, multilevel signalling, and multiple lanes, the signal rate is 125 Mbaud. 2) But the OP isn't asking about that, they're asking about the RGMII signalling, which is a different beast altogether. And it's not clear how the round-trip time of a signal is supposed to equate to its maximum distance…

Comment: GMII interface operates at 125MHz, RGMII also has 125MHz clock but operate on both clock edges for double data rate. Perhaps the real question is whether the chips are even able to work in a mode where RGMII MACs are wired together in a cross-over fashion. Check datasheets and support forums first if you need a PHY. Two PHYs are easier to connect together without magnetics.